# problem in update-migration in visual studio

Tags: c#

I am trying to add migrations in visual studio and i have installed sql server management studio 2014 in my system and successfully connected but when i run "update-database -verbose" migration at package manager console it will display the following error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to locate a Local Database
>   Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server Express is properly
>   installed and that the Local Database Runtime feature is enabled.)

The connection string that i have used in my app.config file are as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ClothBazarConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ClothBazar-Database;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Kindly help...

Comment: Do you have multiple projects in the solution?

Comment: yes i have multiple projects in a solution but i have select a project before where i want to add migrations

Comment: Try to modify connection string by adding `@`   for example `connectionString=@"Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;....."`

Answer (score 0):

Install SQL SERVER EXPRESS from https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadSQLServerExpress.aspx then:

You should try to connect to your SQL Server in Visual Studio with the SQL Server Object Explorer. There you can right click the database and copy the connection string from the properties.

Comment: soryy i dnt have much knowledge about it would you please elaborate it into steps that i can do

Comment: In your visual studio go to View->SQL-Server-Object-Explorer. In the SQL-Server-Object-Explorer connect to your SQL-Server (if not already connected). Then click the small arrow left of your SQL-Server-Name then 'Databases' then right-click your database and select properties. In the properties window you have a connection string propery. This should be the correct connection string to your database.

Comment: there is no option of sql server object explorer there is only server explorer option shoud i choose that??

Comment: what happens if you press [ctrl] with ^ and [ctrl] with S?

Comment: nothing heppend when i press ctrl with ^ and wit ctrl with S

Comment: maybe it helps to install the sqlexpress runtimes from https://www.hanselman.com/blog/DownloadSQLServerExpress.aspx. I think your installation of Visual Studio is incomplete to access databases...

Comment: but sql server management studio already installed and connected also

Comment: the sql server management studio has nothing to do with visual studio. please check your visual studio installation if you have installed SQL-Support or try to install SQL SERVER 2016/2017 EXPRESS from the site above.

Answer (score 0):

In **Package Manager Console** there is a option to select **Default Project** select your project and try command `update-database -verbose` if you already enable the migrations.

Comment: i already select my project where i want to add migrations but showing that error kindly help